# <select> que exibe todas as chaves de um tabela no PHP não retorna as chaves

Tags: php

Eu queria exibir no `<select>` chamado de **Venda** todas as chaves da tabela `itens_venda`, **só que na página não aparece nada**.

Como faço para resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro é especificamente está aqui:

```
<p> Venda:
            <select name="cd_itens_venda" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_selecao as $valor) {
                        echo "<option value='{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}'></option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
```

- Código completo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title> Remover venda </title>
</head>
<body> 
    <?php
        require_once '../conexao/conexao.php';  
        
        if(isset($_POST['Deletar'])){
            
            $cd_itens_venda = $_POST['cd_itens_venda'];

            try {
                
                $remove = "DELETE FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
                $remocao = $conexao->prepare($remove)
                $remocao->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
                $remocao->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $falha_remocao) {
                echo "A remoção não foi feita".$falha_remocao->getMessage();
            }
        }
        // Query que seleciona chave e nome do fornecedor
        $seleciona_nomes = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_itens_venda FROM itens_venda");
        // Resulta em uma matriz
        $resultado_selecao = $seleciona_nomes->fetchAll();  
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <p> Venda:
            <select name="cd_itens_venda" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_selecao as $valor) {
                        echo "<option value='{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}'></option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <button name="Deletar">Deletar venda</button>
    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Faltou executar `$seleciona_nomes->execute();`

   ```
   $seleciona_nomes = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_itens_venda FROM itens_venda");
   $seleciona_nomes->execute();
   ..........
   ```
2. faltou mostrar o texto do option

   ```
   <option value="VALOR A PASSAR">TEXTO MOSTRADO</option>
   ```

   SEU CASO

   ```
   echo "<option value='{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}'>'{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}'</option>";
   ```

Comment: Eu não sabia que podia usar novamente ```{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}'```.

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigado Leo.

Comment: ```$seleciona_nomes->execute();``` eu não uso e vai normal.

Comment: @Cautium, gozado se eu comentar $seleciona_nomes->execute(); não rola. Qual deve ser a sua mágica para rolar? Sera que tem algo diferente no arquivo conexao.php? gostaria de ver o seu. O meu é assim $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Nome_DB', 'User', 'Pass', array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION